# Extending curves on a surface to a basis for its first homology satisfying intersection criteria

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, heegaard-floer-homology

The title suggests a broader scope of inquiry, but my question mostly pertains to the following example:

Let $(Y, \mathcal{Z}, \phi)$ be a bordered 3-manifold with Heegaard diagram $\mathcal{H}$ of genus $g$, and let $k$ be the genus of $F(\mathcal{Z}) \cong \partial Y$. Assume that $\mathcal{Z}$ is the split pointed matched circle. Cap off $\Sigma$ with a disk and close off each $\alpha_i^a$ to $\alpha_i'$ to get a closed genus $g$ surface $\Sigma'$ with $\left\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{g-k}, \alpha_1^{\prime}, \ldots, \alpha_{2 k}^{\prime}\right\}$ spanning a $(g+k)$-dimensional subspace of $H_1(\Sigma')$.

It's evident that $\alpha_i^a,\alpha_{i+1}^a$ are dual with respect to the intersection form $\#(-\cap -):H_1(\Sigma') \times H_1(\Sigma') \to \mathbb{Z}$. I now want to add in circles $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_{g-k}$ such that $\#(\gamma_i \cap \alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$ but $\#(\gamma_i \cap \alpha_j')=0$ for all $i,j$ so as to obtain a basis $\left\{\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_{g-k}, \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{g-k}, \alpha_1^{\prime}, \ldots, \alpha_{2 k}^{\prime}\right\}$ dual to $\left\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{g-k}, \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_{g-k}, \alpha_2^{\prime}, \alpha_1^{\prime}, \ldots, \alpha_{2 k}^{\prime}, \alpha_{2 k-1}^{\prime}\right\}$ with respect to $\#(-\cap -)$. A cartoon picture:

[image]

In this way any $\beta$ could be expressed as a linear combination of $H_1(\Sigma')$ basis elements where coefficients are the intersection numbers of $\beta$ with the respective dual element. For instance, the coefficient of $\beta$ on $\gamma_i$ is $\#(\beta\cap\alpha_i)$.

My question is, under what conditions can we ensure such an extension to a basis is possible? Is the definition of $\mathcal{H}$ doing the heavy lifting (assuming all $\alpha,\beta$ are simple, pairwise disjoint; homological linear independence)? Or is this most restrictive form of $\mathcal{Z}$ the essential piece?

I hope to intimately understand this case so that I can relax some of the assumptions and apply a similar idea to a more general setting. It will be equally helpful if responses prefer to use $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you’re looking for is Lemma A.3 in my paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608373).

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, thank you. 

As a follow up, in my more general case $\Sigma$ is instead a sutured surface $(\Sigma, \Lambda, S_+,S_-)$ and I wish to extend to a basis for $H_1(\Sigma,S_+)$. Here $S_+$ is a disjoint union of intervals on $\partial \Sigma$. I haven't yet fully digested your proof but at first glance it appears to rely on the topology of $\Sigma_g$. Do you suspect that these ideas could port over to the pair $(\Sigma,S_+)$? (Or perhaps a more general question: is there a version of this for any spaces other than $\Sigma_g$?)

Comment: I’m not really sure what sort of generalization you are looking for.  Can you ask a precise question that makes no reference to 3-manifold topology?

Comment: Maybe a good place to start is to ask if a similar result holds when we remove a disk from $\Sigma_g$ (away from the curves) so that it has one boundary component. I think it's true that removing one disk does not change the first homology, but every additional removal of a disk introduces a factor of $\mathbb{Z}$, correct? Apologies, I agree my above "follow up" is imprecise, perhaps I need to sit with your lemma for a bit then post a new question or edit this one.

Comment: @contingent: Yes, that is a correct statement of what removing discs does to homology.  It’s hard to say anything more without a precise question.